# Serving local static files in development

Tags: django, wagtail

I've recently adopted this method of serving our static and media files for our docker containers running a wagtail django site.

[Serving static and media files from S3 wagtail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999600/serving-static-and-media-files-from-s3-wagtail)

I've just realised that I'm going to need to change some things locally in order to be able to serve static files :-(

I don't want to run the collectstatic command for local dev, as that's going to put a load of uneccessary wagtailadmin stuff into the static folder which will then be in the github repo.

Does anyone know how I'd serve the wagtail admin files without running collectstatic?

Comment: Why not just add the static folder to .gitignore? You don't need to keep it in source control, since collectstatic just creates copies anyway.

Comment: Hi Håken, thanks for replying.  I want the devs to use the /static folder to put their static assets into.   I may well be chasing my own tail here if you know what I mean.

Comment: The source assets can be placed in one of the dirs in `STATICFILE_DIRS`. `STATIC_ROOT` can be some other location outside of source control. This is where your files are copied when you run collectstatic (when not using a CDN in production).

Comment: Yeah, for some reason though I don't want to run collectstatic in dev mode, I can't even remember why now.  This is what I mean about chasing my tail.  Thanks Håken, I will go and have a thunk about it a bit more.

Comment: It's useful when testing the full stack in development or staging or on a continuous integration server. I might not want to upload static files to a CDN outside of production.